# Losing "type" information inside polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

Sorry if my question doesn't make a lot of sense. I don't have much experience in python.

I have some code that looks like:

```py
import polars as pl
from typing import NamedTuple


class Event(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    description: str


def event_table(num) -> list[Event]:
    events = []
    for i in range(5):
        events.append(Event("name", "description"))
    return events


def pretty_string(events: list[Event]) -> str:
    pretty = ""
    for event in events:
        pretty += f"{event.name}: {event.description}\n"
    return pretty

# This does work
print(pretty_string(event_table(5)))

# But then it doesn't work if I have my `list[Event]` in a dataframe
data = {"events": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data).select(events=pl.col("events").map_elements(event_table))

# This doesn't work
pretty_df = df.select(events=pl.col("events").map_elements(pretty_string))
print(pretty_df)

# Neither does this
print(pretty_string(df["events"][0]))
```

It fails with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/script.py", line 32, in <module>
    pretty_df = df.select(events=pl.col("events").map_elements(pretty_string))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/to/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/dataframe/frame.py", line 8116, in select
    return self.lazy().select(*exprs, **named_exprs).collect(_eager=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path/to/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py", line 1934, in collect
    return wrap_df(ldf.collect())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
polars.exceptions.ComputeError: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Looks like my `list[Event]` is no longer that inside the `df`. I am not sure how to go about getting this to work.

Comment: You can keep the `Event` type with `.map_elements(event_table, return_dtype=pl.Object))` - is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks. That fixed my issue. If you want to post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the Event objects by passing `return_dtype=pl.Object`

```py
df.select(pl.col("events").map_elements(event_table))
```

```py
shape: (5, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ events                            │
│ ---                               │
│ list[struct[2]]                   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ [{"name","description"}, {"name"… │
│ [{"name","description"}, {"name"… │
│ [{"name","description"}, {"name"… │
│ [{"name","description"}, {"name"… │
│ [{"name","description"}, {"name"… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

```py
df.select(pl.col("events").map_elements(event_table, return_dtype=pl.Object))
```

```py
shape: (5, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ events                            │
│ ---                               │
│ object                            │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ [Event(name='name', description=… │
│ [Event(name='name', description=… │
│ [Event(name='name', description=… │
│ [Event(name='name', description=… │
│ [Event(name='name', description=… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: This doesn't allow me to `explode` the df later. Is there a way to keep the type as a list of the object? I tried `return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Object)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @DJDuque You cannot create `list[object]`. The `pl.Object` type is *"extremely limited*" - it basically means: *"Polars does not support this item"*. If you want to actually use these values inside Polars, you cannot keep the object type.